# Err no:105 phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Im getting an error in phpmyadmin creating these tables, but i don't know why

```
DROP TABLE customer, reservation;
CREATE TABLE customer(
    id          INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    f_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    l_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE reservation(
    r_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    book_date   DATE NOT NULL CHECK (book_date <= now()),
    s_time      DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    e_time      DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    amount      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_ID) REFERENCES customer(customer_ID) 
);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: #1005 - Can't create table 'test.reservation' (errno: 150)

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'test.reservation' (errno: 150)

Comment: Usually the error you get would be a very helpfull information.

Comment: Which *query* generates that error? If it's the `DROP TABLES` part, you're trying to drop `customer`, which `reservation` references as a foreign key. errno 150 is usually a FK error.

Answer (score 0):

After quick googling found this. Might help:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,373154#msg-373154

Answer (score 0):

The query works for me.  You should check your permissions to make sure you have `CREATE` permissions.